# How to access a a specific key from an associative array in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I've an associative array which is assigned to smarty template. 
There, I'm not understanding how to access one specific key. I researched about it, but could't get the specific solution.
The scenario is as follows :

My php array named `$all_class_subjects` is as follows :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 1
            [class_name] => I
            [I] => Array
                (
                    [cs_map_id] => 
                    [cs_class_id] => 
                    [cs_subject_id] => 
                    [subjects] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 2
            [class_name] => II
            [II] => Array
                (
                    [cs_map_id] => 
                    [cs_class_id] => 
                    [cs_subject_id] => 
                    [subjects] => 
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
            [class_name] => III
            [III] => Array
                (
                    [cs_map_id] => 
                    [cs_class_id] => 
                    [cs_subject_id] => 
                    [subjects] => 
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 4
            [class_name] => IV
            [IV] => Array
                (
                    [cs_map_id] => 
                    [cs_class_id] => 
                    [cs_subject_id] => 
                    [subjects] => 
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 5
            [class_name] => V
            [V] => Array
                (
                    [cs_map_id] => 1
                    [cs_class_id] => 5
                    [cs_subject_id] => 3
                    [subjects] => Array
                        (
                            [subject_name] => Mathematics
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 6
            [class_name] => VI
            [VI] => Array
                (
                    [cs_map_id] => 2
                    [cs_class_id] => 6
                    [cs_subject_id] => 4
                    [subjects] => Array
                        (
                            [subject_name] => Biology
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now I want to print values from this array in smarty template. The code snippet is as below It may have few HTML errors:

```
{if $all_class_subjects}
         {foreach from=$all_class_subjects item=class_subject_data}
       <tr>
           <td width="20%">{$class_subject_data.class_name|capitalize}</td>
           <td width="40%">
            {foreach from=class_subject_data item=subject}

            {if $subject.cls_sub_subject_name} 
             {$class_subject_data.cs_subject_id}
```

My question is I want to check whether the array

```
[I] => Array
            (
                [cs_map_id] => 
                [cs_class_id] => 
                [cs_subject_id] => 
                [subjects] => 
            )
```

is empty or not. You can see except the last two elements all the array elements have these fields empty.
So in short my question is how to access the internal array containing above fields as the index of array i.e. key(I, II, III, IV, etc.) are changing?
The PHP function which returns the array is as follow :

```
function GetAllClassSubjects( $cur_page, $sort_col_id, $desc_or_asc, $request) { 
        global $grid;

      $grid->mSqlArr['fields']  = " classes.class_id, classes.class_name" ;
          $grid->mSqlArr['tables']  =   TBL_CLASSES." AS classes ";
          $grid->mSqlArr['orderby'] = "classes.class_order";

          $grid->mSqlArr['where'] = "";

          $grid->mCurPage    = $cur_page;
          $grid->mRecPerPage = REC_PER_PAGE; //default is 20
          $grid->mSortColumns->mColsArr = array('class_id');
          $grid->mSortColumns->mDefaultOrderStr = "";
          $grid->mSortColumns->mCurColNo        = $sort_col_id;
          $grid->mSortColumns->mCurSortOrder    = "DESC";
          $class_data = $grid->GetData();

          //print_p($class_data);
      $grid->mSqlArr['fields']  = " class_subject_mapping.cs_map_id, class_subject_mapping.cs_class_id, class_subject_mapping.cs_subject_id" ;
          $grid->mSqlArr['tables']  =   TBL_CLASS_SUBJECT_MAPPING." AS class_subject_mapping ";
          $grid->mSqlArr['orderby'] = "";

          $grid->mSqlArr['where'] = "";

            $grid->mCurPage    = $cur_page;
            $grid->mRecPerPage = REC_PER_PAGE; //default is 20
            $grid->mSortColumns->mColsArr = array('cs_map_id');
            $grid->mSortColumns->mDefaultOrderStr = "";
            $grid->mSortColumns->mCurColNo        = $sort_col_id;
            $grid->mSortColumns->mCurSortOrder    = "DESC";
            $mapping_data = $grid->GetData();
            //print_p($mapping_data);   

      foreach($class_data as $class)
      {
        $flag = 0;
        $class_id = $class['class_id'];
        $class_name = $class['class_name'];

            foreach($mapping_data as $class_subject)
            {
                $cs_map_id = $class_subject['cs_map_id'];
                $cs_class_id = $class_subject['cs_class_id'];
                $cs_subject_id = $class_subject['cs_subject_id'];


                    if($class_id == $cs_class_id)
                    {
                            $flag = 1;
                            $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['cs_map_id'] = $cs_map_id;
                            $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['cs_class_id'] = $cs_class_id;
                            $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['cs_subject_id'] = $cs_subject_id;

                            $sql  = " SELECT subject_name";
                                    $sql .= " FROM ".TBL_SUBJECTS." AS subjects";
                                    $sql .= " WHERE subjects.subject_id = ".$cs_subject_id;
                                    $sql .= " order by subject_order";

                                    $this->mDb->Query( $sql);
                                    $class_subjects_data = $this->mDb->FetchArray();
                                    //print_p($class_subjects_data);

                                    foreach($class_subjects_data as $sub)
                                    {
                                        $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['subjects'] = $sub;
                                    }
                            }                           
                    }
                    if($flag == 0)
                    {
                        $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['cs_map_id'] = "";
                $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['cs_class_id'] = "";
                $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['cs_subject_id'] = "";
                $class_data[$class_id-1][$class_name]['subjects'] = "";

                    }   
      }
      print_p($class_data);

        //ksort($cls_sub_data[$cs_map_id]); 

    //print_p($cls_sub_data);
    list( $sort_url_param, $sort_col_array, $pagination_array ) =
        $grid->GetUrlParam( PAGE_OFFSET, PHP_SELF."?op=".$query_string."&", "col", 'order', 'page' );

        return array($class_data, $sort_url_param, $sort_col_array, $pagination_array );
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you changing the `key` of the array you are needing to check instead of keeping it static throughout and using the `class_name` for anything you may need the roman numeral for in smarty?

Comment: @Jon Your suggestion is nice but can't implement in this scenario. I've added the function code to the question which returns the array.

Comment: can you post the complete `{if}{/if}` structure of your smarty code?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your outer `{foreach}`, `{$class_subject_data[$class_subject_data.class_name]}` will give you the desired

```
Array(
    [cs_map_id] => 
    [cs_class_id] => 
    [cs_subject_id] => 
    [subjects] => 
)
```

for current `item=class_subject_data`

Try this code, it *should* print all your desired arrays.

```
{if $all_class_subjects}
    {foreach from=$all_class_subjects item=class_subject_data}
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">{$class_subject_data.class_name|capitalize}</td>
            <td width="40%">
                {assign var='desired_array' value=$class_subject_data[$class_subject_data.class_name]}

                <pre>{$desired_array|@print_r:1}</pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {/foreach}
 {/if}
```

### Update

Assuming the above code prints the desired array for you, the `{$desired_array}` is

```
array(
    [cs_map_id] => 
    [cs_class_id] => 
    [cs_subject_id] => 
    [subjects] =>
)
```

So it contains the keys, e.g., `{desired_array.cs_map_id}`, `{desired_array.cs_class_id}` etc

Comment: Can u plz put in specific variable names which will print all the values. Because I couldn't get any clear idea of how to achieve it. Please don't consider the code snippet I used in the question to print the array.

Comment: assuming it printed the _desired_array_ for you, `$desired_array` is `Array(
    'cs_map_id' => '', 
    'cs_class_id' => '', 
    'cs_subject_id' => '',
    'subjects' => '',)`. So it has keys like, `{$desired_array.cs_map_id}`, `{$desired_array.cs_class_id}` etc.